# Does Entity Framework support generic relations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Does Entity Framework support generic relations?
E.g.

```
public class Comment<T> : Entity
   where T : Entity
{
   public string Text { get; set; }
   public long EntityId { get; set; }
   public T Entity { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentComment : Comment<Document> {
}

public class DeliveryComment : Comment<Delivery> {
}
```

UPDATE: I'll expand on my process as I tried this.
I tried creating configurations to make it work as I figured I needed to specify the types of variables but got an error when trying to add the migration.

```
public class CommentConfiguration<TU,T> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TU>
   where TU : Comment<T>
   where T : Entity
{
   public Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TU> builder)
   {
      builder.ToTable(nameof(Comment));
      builder.Property(x => x.Id);
      builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

      builder.HasOne(x => x.Entity)
         .WithMany()
         .HasForeignKey(x => x.EntityId)
         .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade)

   }
}

public class DocumentCommentConfiguration : CommentConfiguration<DocumentComment,Document>
{
   public Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<DocumentComment> builder)
   {
   }
}

public class DeliveryCommentConfiguration : CommentConfiguration<DeliveryComment,Delivery>
{
   public Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<DeliveryComment> builder)
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? It should be very easy to test.

Comment: @GuruStron I updated the question with what i tried, though I did not save the error that i got

Comment: EF classes and methods are generic already. DbSet<> is generic. LINQ methods are generic. What are you actually trying to do? Are you sure you aren't trying to generalize what is already generic?

Comment: `got an error when trying to add the migration.` that's a completely different question. Migrations is where generic types have to become concrete SQL. The migrations feature of EF is an ease-of-use feature and *nowhere* near as powerful as schema migration tools like Redgate's. No ORM comes close to these. ORM tools can produce simple migration scripts like adding or dropping a column, but for complex things, you'll probably have to add custom SQL scripts. For example, splitting a column in two can't be inferred from entities and their properties

Comment: I would want the sql to create a EntityId that I can use in EF as different entity types, since comment is related to many different entities. I wanted to avoid having multiple columns of null Ids as each comment is only related to one entity at a time. A DocumentComment would be a comment related to a Document, and a DeliveryComment would be related to a Delivery but they would share the entityId row. I have seen EF create a discriminator column and I was hoping for it to do the same in this case.

Comment: Yes it does. Do you want TPT, TPH or TPC? It sounds like TPT

Comment: Note `nameof(Comment)` will always return the string "Comment". Was that your intention?

Answer (score 1):

Actually using conventions based setup worked just fine for me, so (at least based on provided info) you don't need to provide `IEntityTypeConfiguration`'s.

If you still want to then (apart from the compilation issues, cause currently provided code is not compliable) you need to fix the table name in `CommentConfiguration<TU,T>` (by default you can't map different entity types to the same table). For example:

```
public class CommentConfiguration<TU,T> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TU>
   where TU : Comment<T>
   where T : Entity
{
   public Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TU> builder)
   {
      builder.ToTable(typeof(TU).Name);
      // ... rest of the config
   }
}
```

[Full code sample](https://gist.github.com/gurustron/92aab822f6c4aa41575ac47119e75d88) used for testing.

Also can be useful - [inheritance in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-hierarchy-and-discriminator-configuration).